# SQL Set variable to select result

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I was wondering if it is possible to set a declared variable to a return value from a select result? Something like:

```
@WatchedSeconds
SET @WatchedSeconds = 200
DECLARE @SelectedVideo int
SET @SelectedVideo = (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Video v WHERE v.VideoID = 12)

IF @SelectedVideo IS NOT NULL
   BEGIN
      IF @SelectedVideo.VideoLength = @WatchedSeconds
        BEGIN
           --DO SOMETHING
        END
      IF @SelectedVideo.SomeOtherColumn = @SomethingElse
        BEGIN
        END
   END
```

It's for using some information from the `SELECT` result multiple places in a `Stored Procedure`.
I know that I can set a variable to e.g, a integer, and set it to the selected result, if it returns a integer, e.g:

```
DECLARE @VideoSeconds int
SET @VideoSeconds = (SELECT v.Length FROM Video v WHERE v.VideoID = @VideoID)
```

This way I have to make multiple variables, and multiple `SELECT` calls if I need to use more values from the `Video` result. And that's what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like

(declare variables first...)

```
SELECT TOP 1 @var1=col1, @var2=col2, @var3=col3, [...] FROM YourTable WHERE YourFilter
```

EDIT: All together this seems not to be the best approach... With SQL you should not think in values and single rows but rather in result sets (set based programming). Your thinking leads to many tiny selects, while loops, cursors and all this stuff one should avoid.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.
Yes, I'm not normally dealing that much with SQL, so I did not know that. But how would you approach this then, to avoid the tiny select statements even more?

Comment: Without knowing your tables and what exactly you want to reach it is impossible to give you an answer. Just some hints: Best is an ad-hoc solution: one single statement returns all you need. Set based pre-work is done with CTE and row-based post-work with APPLY. But - to be honest - if you don't deal so much with SQL you don't have to dive into it so deeply :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this simply by running:

```
SELECT @videoSeconds = v.Length FROM Video v WHERE v.VideoID = @VideoID
```

so as to not add the `SET` part.

Also, you must make sure that only  1 row is being returned by the query, otherwise it will generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the results in a temporary table or table variable:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
INTO #SelectedVideo
FROM Video v
WHERE v.VideoID = 12;
```

Then you can assign values from the table later in your code.  Something like:

```
IF ( (SELECT VideoLength FROM #SelectedVideo) = @WatchedSeconds)
```

However, for your particular example, if you have an index on `video(VideoId)`, then there is little to be gained performance-wise from using a temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to get is similar to returning a dataset in a procedural language (so you can type something like Result.Field1 = 'Test') then I don't think this is possible. You'll just need to declare multiple variables and make the SELECT call as

```
SELECT TOP 1 @var1=col1, @var2=col2, @var3=col3, [...] FROM YourTable WHERE YourFilter
```

as @Shnugo suggests

The 'dataset' equivalent structure in SQL is cursors, but they require variables to be set up as well, so there's no benefit there.

Comment: The dataset equivalent is not a cursor... A cursor (maybe) could be compared to a DataReader. But: Trying to transfer concepts of a sequential programming language over to a set based one is exactly the wrong way round... I'm dealing with SQL heavily but I **never** use cursors if I can avoid them. And I could avoid them within the last years pretty well :-)

Comment: Datareaders aren't in my main development language, so I wouldn't have made that suggestion automatically, but I'm implying something that you can just have the table as a variable and then refer to fields directly rather than having to declare each field, which was what was implied by the question (I have to make multiple variables... And that's what I want to avoid) and was not being addressed by the other answers. Probably should have qualified the comment as 'the closest equivalent to', as I think that was the type of usage OP was aiming for